# User Identity in all ViewModels

Tags: zend-framework2

I use `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` to manage the currently logged in user. Now I want the entity object to be available in all ViewModels by default without having to assign the user object in every controller action.

Is there a nice way to do this? Or do I need to create a Factory for ViewModels and inject the user’s identity from there? In that case I would have to use the ServiceManager every time I wanted to create a ViewModel, which is not quite sexy.

Is there a more elegant way? Can I perhaps somehow access the AuthenticationService directly from within the ViewModel (i.e. the template)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by the the answers of Ocramius and Bram, I took a deeper look into the ZF View Helpers. And tadaa: As it turns out, **ZF2 already comes with a Helper to access the user identity** in any View Model. The View Helper is simply called `identity`.

In order for it to work though, you need to add `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` to the list of invokable classes (no clue, why this isn’t default) e.g. in your *config/autoload/global.php*:

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService',
        ),
    ),
);
```

After that you can easily acces the current user’s identity from any template:

```
<p>Hello <?php echo $this->identity()->getName() ?></p>
```

Thanks again especially to Ocramius for getting me on the right track! If you don’t use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService his answer still applies.

Comment: the auth service of `ZfcUser` is still a `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` btw ;)

Answer (score 2):

Look at how [`ZfcUser`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) does it. Instead of injecting the identity variable in all views, it allows a [view helper](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/0.1.0/src/ZfcUser/View/Helper/ZfcUserIdentity.php) to access the authentication service.

To do so, the authentication service is injected in the view helper [through a service factory](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/0.1.0/Module.php#L62-L67).

This basically allows you to use something like following in any of your view scripts:

```
echo $user = $this->zfcUserIdentity();

echo $user ? $user->getUsername() : 'Not logged in!';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view helper wich retrieves the user model from the authentication service.
Have a look at the ZfcUser [view helper](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/View/Helper/ZfcUserIdentity.php) for an example.
Maybe you could use ZfcUser module for your use case.